# MYSQL: Two fields as PRIMARY KEYs + 1 Field as UNIQUE, a question

Tags: mysql, database-design, indexing, unique, auto-increment

I have two primary (composite) keys that refer to a shop and a branch.
I thought I should have used a corresponding ID for each row, so I added a UNIQUE + AUTO_INCREMENT named ID.

So I had on the table a column named ID (AUTO INCREMENT), but it was declared PRIMARY - which was done automatically, and I don't want the ID to be PRIMARY. Just the shop and branch.

I have learnt how to trick MYSQL to accept the ID field as UNIQUE and AUTO INCREMENT, as it was not extremely trivial to make the AUTO_INCREMENT (it wanted to make it PRIMARY).
I had to ERASE the ID Field (for some reason it didn't let me erase its PRIMARY index), then declare it INDEX, and only then AUTO INCREMENT.

Is that a good approach ? 
Could there be something I am doing wrong going with this design ?

Thanks !!!

Comment: What's the point of having autoincrement ID which is not the primary key? Shorter primary keys are better, and in InnoDB there are advantages in using autoincrement as primary key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prevailing wisdom is that every table should have a unique autonumbered column named Id.

In classical data modeling, as developed by Codd and Date,  the ID field is not necessary for a complete logical model of the data.

What good does the ID field do you?  Do you ever reference a row in this table by its ID?  If never, then just leave the field out.  (shop, branch) provided a perfectly good candidate to be the PK.

Comment: Thanks !! I think I will simply go on

Comment: dough... :) I think I will simply go ahead and make two tables. One be a companies tables, and the other, a branches table where the ref would be from the branches to the companies. in the branches I will create a third key that would be unique which would be business_id, and with that I will work throughout the whole scheme. Does that sound reasonable enough ?

Answer (score 0):

What did your `create table` statement look like?  Because I imagine this:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    IDCol int not null auto_increment,
    shop int not null,
    branch int not null,

    /* ... */

    UNIQUE KEY IDCol (IDCol),
    PRIMARY KEY (shop, branch)
);
```

Comment: I have to say I used phpMyAdmin for that, and I did not keep record of that.

Comment: As I was doing the steps I meantioned before for all my other tables there seems to be no problem, ie. ERASE ID, add it again, declare it as UNIQUE, and only then AUTO INCREMENT

Comment: It seems like you're tricking phpMyAdmin into doing what you want, not MySQL.  I don't know any phpMyAdmin tricks to make it do what you want other than just manually writing out the `CREATE` query oneself.  Good luck.