# MySQL Dual Column Primary Key Dilemma

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

Here's the situation -> I'm working with two columns of data (A and B - both ints) in a MySQL environment. A and B are **non-unique** attributes, but each row/slice of A & B has to be unique.

For example these are valid entries:

```
A      B
---    ---
1      1
1      2
1      3
```

In this case below the third row in invalid cause it breaks the rule that each combo of A and B has to be unique:

```
A      B
---    ---
1      2
1      3
1      2
```

What's the best way for me to model this type of relationship in a MySQL setting where the combined effect of two columns creates a primary key? Can I reduce this logic down to one primary key? In that case, how do I make sure that each new row doesn't violate the rule?

Comment: Check out [both answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494276/mysql-two-fields-as-primary-keys-1-field-as-unique-a-question)

Comment: Why don't you simply have a two column primary key?

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I'm new to this stuff and didn't you could have two column primary keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a unique index:

```
 ALTER TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE INDEX (`A`, `B`);
```

You will have to de-dup the table before this query will work, but once it does, then you are guaranteed to have unique A+B rows in the table.  Queries can use both, but do not have to:

```
 SELECT * from `table` WHERE `A`=1 and `B`=2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! How does this approach differ from creating a two column primary key as mentioned by Dan Bracuk?

Comment: You do not need both values for A and B.

Answer (score 1):

You can either create a new, arbitrary key value (typically a sequential integer), or you can create a composite key from the two columns.